# How to get Underscore's map to only return based on a condition

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I currently have the following:

```
flatArray = _.map(items, function(x){ return x.count; });
```

This returns an array like so:

```
[6,6,3,0,0,0,1,0]
```

How can I get just the # of items where count is Gt 0. In this case, how can I get just the number 4.

I'm using underscore and jQuery.

Comment: Apply `.filter()` + `.length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a _.reduce to get a count of items > 0:

`_.reduce(items, function(m,x) { return m + (x > 0 ? 1: 0); });`

Comment: "m" will start at 0 and "x" is the value pulled from each element in the array, "m" is the accumulator passed between each function call

Comment: You'll need to give a seed of `0`, otherwise the `m` will start at the value of the first item in the Array.

Comment: That is returning - `[object Object]100000000000000000000000 `

Comment: cookie monster, my mistake.
`_.chain(items).filter(function(x) { return x > 0}).value().length;`
should do it

Comment: `_.reduce(items, function(m,x) { return m + (x.count > 0 ? 1: 0); }, 0);`

Comment: @cookiemonster, even better

Answer (score 1):

May not be the best way, but

```
var flatArray = [];
_.each(items, function(x)
{
    if (x > 0) flatArray.push(x);
});

console.log(flatArray) // prints [6,6,3,1]
```

Comment: Thanks, What is the best way?

Answer (score 1):

```
var cnt = _.map(items, function(x){ return x.count; })
           .filter(function(i) { return i > 0; })
           .length;
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cwF4X/1/

Comment: Thanks but that's returning 16, not 4.

Comment: @AnApprentice: then the result from the question is not correct. If it returns 16 then there are 16 elements that are equal to 0

Comment: @cookie monster: oh god, I don't even expect to see a 15k person who is not able to replace `==` with `>`. It is just weird

Comment: I think your `map()` is extraneous; the extraction of `count` can just as easily be done inside the filter predicate.

Comment: @S McCrohan: it's arguable. I think it's a more "functional" solution. Also have a look at here: http://jsfiddle.net/cwF4X/2/

Comment: Also worth noting, this won't work on older browsers because Array.filter is not supported. You'd have to `_.chain` this call in order for it to reliably work on all browsers. Or have an Array.filter polyfill

Comment: @Cory Danielson: "older browsers" --- it must be terrible to a developer that ought to support ie8

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter()`:

Example as in the [docs](http://underscorejs.org/#filter):

```
var evens = _.filter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], function(num){ return num % 2 == 0; });
```

Here `evens` will be an array of even numbers (`num % 2 == 0` )

For your case to get the required count:

```
var count = _.map(items, function(x){ return x.count; })
               .filter(function(i) { return i > 0; })
               .length;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this - here are two:

```
var cnt = _.filter(items, function(x) { return x.count > 0; }).length;

var cnt = _.reduce(items, function(count, item) { return count + (item.count > 0 ? 1 : 0); }, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the _.reduce item but it always returns 1.

Comment: @AnApprentice: do you seriously cannot handle it for already 15 minutes?

Comment: SMcCrohan: I think you have an operator precedence issue with the conditional operator next to the `+`.

Comment: cookie monster - yeah, misplaced ). Fixed.